# How to store coordinates from cascaded_union

Tags: python, arrays, shapely

I have a code that performs the union of a set of triangles, using the function `cascaded_union()` in shapely in python.

```
print cascaded_union(triangle)
```

When I print it, it gives the following output:-

```
POLYGON ((211 55, 0 0, 150 204, 185 216, 215 159, 224 132, 211 55))
```

How can I store these points in a 2-d array with `x` and `y` coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you specifically need to store the geometry as a 2d array? For example, is it an option to store the geometry using Well Known Text (WKT) format, which is easily produced by shapely, e.g. `my_polygon.wkt`, and then storing this output in text or CSV format? You can later reload this geometry using shapely's `wkt.loads()` method. Though you could also store the WKT in a key-value store such as Redis.

If binary is preferred, you can similarly use the WKB functionality. But if you are going to be doing a lot of this kind of thing, then think about using a full-fledged GIS database such as PostGIS, which can natively work with such geometry types.

However, if you specifically require the 2d array, then you first need to access the polygon's exterior linearRing component in shapely, then cast it to a numpy array. In other words:

```
from shapely import geometry
import numpy as np
my_poly = cascaded_union(triangle)
my_2d_array = np.array(my_poly.exterior)
print(my_2d_array)
```

You'll need to repeat this for any interior components / holes inside the polygon, if present.